# Exporting OpenStreetMap building blocks boundaries to polygon shapefile

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapping

I am using QGIS software to draw building blocks boundaries that appear on [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) as shown in the following image

[image]

but as you can see it can not be accurate.

Is there a way to export the building blocks boundaries from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) to a polygon shapefile??

I already checked the website Map data and also tried OSM downloader plugin in QGIS but it does not have such required data.

Comment: Have you checked with the OSm-wiki, if a tag exists fitting your needs? If so, OSM downloader should be fine.

Comment: shapefiles with building blocks/buildings are available in shapefile format https://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html

Comment: I've checked it but it didn't help @Erik

Comment: I've downloaded the shapefile of the map of my area and it turns out there are no such data. It seems that the street lines make the boundaries of these blocks. is there a way to convert the street line into these boundaries to make the polygon data required?? @Mapperz